# From Angular 2 to Angular 4 - File size reduction and speed enhancement

Tags: angular

I'm using Webpack and upgraded from Angular 2 to Angular 4 successfully. However I'm not seeing the expected 60% file size reductions neither my compiled vendors.js nor app.js.

*vendor.js*
before: 913kb
now: 975kb

*app.js*
before: 308kb
now: 307kb

What am I missing? Do we need to use Angular CLI to take advantage of the file size reduction?

my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.1.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url": "^0.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "~2.1.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use AoT, ES2015 modules and latest Webpack to feel the difference (and it's highly unlikely that it will be 60% or something). The reference to *vendors* is pointless since it isn't clear the reduction of *what* you expect. So are file sizes. You have to compare minified, gzipped files.

Comment: Listen more carefully to the comments in those conference talks. They are  talking about more aggressive tree shaking and minification and frequently mention "closure" as oppsed to the cli bundled webpack. Also **every** mention is of much larger projects than you are referencing here. So it's mostly a matter of 'scale', and to some extent different tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Estus comment (and thank you). We need to use AoT (Ahead of Time Compilation) not the usual JiT (Just in Time Compilation) in order to take advantage of Angular 4 size reduction and speed enhancement. Using AoT with Angular Cli with create AoT for client browsers (platform-browser).

See [Angular ahead-of-time compilation cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)

It is not to be confused with running Angular on the server for search engines indexing and SEO benefits using Universal (another form of AoT using platform-server).

[Angular Universal Doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/universal.html)